# mypy can't decide on the correct type of an import if it's cimported when cython.compiled

Tags: python, import, python-import, cython, mypy

Given this code

```py
if cython.compiled:
    from cython.cimports.libc.math import abs, pi  # type: ignore
    from cython.cimports.crujisim.types.base import VectorAware # type: ignore

else:
    from .base import VectorAware
    from math import pi

p = pi


@cython.cclass
class Bearing(VectorAware):

    @staticmethod
    @cython.cfunc
    def from_value(value: float) -> Bearing:
        instance: Bearing = Bearing.__new__(Bearing)
        instance.is_vector = False
```

mypy will report `p` as being `Any | float`. Same with any other class that is cimported. This makes static typing almost useless for the file.

The `#type: ignore` simply avoids the warning, although that's also the underlying issue for the Any reported by mypy.

---

More info on my specific problem. This is part of a large codebase and I do find static type checking useful. But in the previous (edited) example, mypy complains that it can't determine the type of instance.is_vector, even though it is a properly typed attribute of VectorAware. But mypy can't properly decide what VectorAware is since it's behind an if, and in once case it can't tell what it is because it's a cimport, not an import.

For completeness, here is a reduced definition of `VectorAware` in base.py

```py
@cython.cclass
class VectorAware:
    is_vector: bool
    length: int
    _vector: np.ndarray
```

Incidentally it was all working fine while both Bearing and VectorAware were on the same file, but once it got too big, had to split and then do cimports static typing is messed up.

Is there any workaround I could use?

Comment: You have been using the duck-typing concept of Python nicely. It does not matter what `pi` is and where it comes from as long as I can use it. Taking this into account it makes your question on how to go the path of static typing (a concept the is not native to Python BTW) rather surprising. So, do you want to have static typing of not?

Comment: Edited the question to include an example of were the issues come up. I would prefer to keep static checks as part of the toolset. If not I would accept that it's not available in these modules. The regular python classes using these can have static typing, although I'm forced to use .pyi files, which before the split I didn't have to.